# New to react, useEffect not working how I would expect with utility functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

First of all, new to react.  Been banging my head against the desk with this one..

Trying to fetch and display a list of items:

```
// Things.jsx

//imports...
 

export default function Things() {
  const [things, setThings] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {  
      // enabling request cancellation
      ThingsAPI.getAll().then((things) => {
          setThings(things)
          console.log( "setThings(things) = " + things)
      })
}, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Heading>Things</Heading>
      <Divider p="10px" />
      <Spacer p="10px" />
      { things && <ThingsList things={things} title="All The Things" /> }
    </div>
  )
}
```

and I have an API class...

```
// ThingsAPI.js

import React from 'react'
import { get } from 'react-hook-form';

const URL_STRING="http://localhost:8888/things"

export const ThingsAPI = {
    getAll: async function() {
        fetch(URL_STRING)
            .then((response) => {
                
                console.log("return response.json()")
                return response.json();
            })
            .then( data => {
                console.log("return data")
                return data
            })
    },

    get: async function(thingId) {
      // todo
    }
}
```

And looking at my console, I get...

```
setThings(things) = undefined
return response.json()
return data
```

So, what's happening is that the page doesn't initially display anything, because the things const is empty.  But when the getAll() function in ThingsAPI returns data.. it never makes it to the setThings() in the page.

If I move the `fetch` call out of the utility class, and into the `useEffect` on the page, it all works.

I've got to be missing something right in front of me, that I just don't get because i'm only a couple of days into React.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: You don't return anything in the `getAll` function. If you `return fetch(URL_STRING)` probably will work as expected

Comment: getAll needs a return - `return fetch(…).then(…)`

Comment: Not sure if i should laugh or cry.  But that was 100% the problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getAll` method defined inside `ThingsAPI`, you are not returning the `Promise` returned by the `fetch` call. Because of this, `ThingsAPI.getAll().then(...)` inside the `useEffect` does not actually wait for the response to be received.

Simply add a return to fix this. Notice that you don't need to mark this method as `async`, since you're not using `await` inside it.

```js
  getAll: function () {
    return fetch(URL_STRING)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('return response.json()');
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log('return data');
        return data;
      });
  },
```